# Custom Video Progress Bar Resets When Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

Working with YouTube's embeddable videos and creating an external progress bar.

First issue I run into is that I can only seek backwards (as in, the only time the seek bar adjusts is when I click on part of the progress bar that has already occurred. I believe this has to do with which `div` I'm using).

Second, when I do click to seek back in time, the video simply resets itself..as if the value it receives is "null or 0."

Relevant HTML

```
<section id="progress-bar-container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="progress-bar-bottom" id="progress-bar-bottom"></div>
        <div class="progress-background"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Relevant JS/JQuery (however let me know if you need to see something else)

```
var onPlayerReady = function (event) {
  console.log("onPlayerReady");

  time_total = convert_to_mins_and_secs(player.getDuration(), 1);

  jQuery(".progress-bar-bottom").on("mouseup touchend", function (event) {
    // Calculate new time for the video
    // duration * ( value of range input / 100 )
    var newTime = player.getDuration() * (event.target.value / 100);
      console.log(newTime);

    // Skip video to new time.
    player.seekTo(newTime);
  });

  $musicBar.css({
    marginBottom: 0,
    transition: "all 200ms ease-in-out"
  });
}
```

Edit: here is the live site! https://www.uncvrd.co/

Comment: I checked the page now and what I discovered was that the div that has the `onclick` event is actually the one moving (being transitioned). Therefore, you can't click on a place the bar has not gotten to. You may need to re-arrange your html elements. This `event.target.value` is attempting to get the value of the div (and divs don't have any). You should try `event.pageX`. It gets the x coordinates of the click

Comment: hi @FemiOladeji thanks for your help so far! Ok so I added a div on top. Now dealing with where it seems that 0-100% is only in the first segment of the progress bar. Heres an image of what I'm talking about: https://snag.gy/aKVhNy.jpg

Comment: if I were to click where the arrow is, the progress bar ends up at about the halfway mark

Comment: `event.pageX` actually returns the absolute px value. You can use `(event.pageX / $('.seek-bar').width()) * 100`. That will give you the percentage of the position that was clicked relative to the width of the seek-bar itself

Comment: @FemiOladeji ah figured it out! So using your method I had to remove the scaling 100 factor since I was multiplying the duration (just a heads up). If you make an answer I will mark as correct!

Comment: side note: there is a delay when clicking to a new part of the seek bar until the bar starts moving to the desired location. Do you know how to fix that..?

Comment: I experienced the same issue a while back and it's because of the transition effect `transition: "all 200ms ease-in-out"`. All you have to do is remove that transition whenever the seek-bar is clicked and then add it back for it's normal interval movement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is re-arrange the html element so that the `onclick` event will be on that. Currently the `onclick` is on the moving div (the div being transitioned). Let's assume this is the new arrangement

```
<section id="progress-bar-container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="seek-bar"></div>
        <div class="progress-bar-bottom" id="progress-bar-bottom"></div>
        <div class="progress-background"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

`event.target.value` attempts to get the value of the div (but divs don't have value). What you want to use is `event.pageX` so that you can get the x coordinates and then find the fraction of the position relative to the seek-bar div.

The javascript portion will then be like this

```
jQuery(".seek-bar").on("mouseup touchend", function (event) {
    // Calculate new time for the video
    // duration * ( value of range input / 100 )
    var newTime = player.getDuration() * (event.pageX / $('.seek-bar').width());
      console.log(newTime);

    // Skip video to new time.
    player.seekTo(newTime);
  });
```

Comment: this will be correct, however I should not be multiplying by 100 since this scaling factor is multiplied with the duration! did you see me extra comment by the way?

Comment: True, that was a mistake, I've fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out